# Getting Navigation functions from HTML5 Video when Streaming from C# .NET

Tags: c#, html, video-streaming

I am trying to provide a modicum of content protection for video that is displayed using the HTML5  tag.

I have attempted to do this by serving the video from my C# .NET application using a one-time-only token.

I have had success delivering the video (it plays), but I am unable to use the player's navigation bar. That is, I can't click on the progress bar to change the player's current position. The position indicator just snaps back to the original location and resumes. Also, once the video has played, it cannot be played again without reloading the page.

I have disabled the "one-time-only" part of my token. So it's not the single-use that's a problem. It has something to do with the way I am serving the file. I have tried returning the C# File object and also FileStream object as the result, with the same effect.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

//HERE IS THE VIEW

@{
    Guid aGuid;

```
string Guidstr;

aGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

Guidstr = aGuid.ToString();

Session[Guidstr] =@"Chrome_ImF.mp4" ;
```

}

///HERE IS THE CONTROLLER CODE

```
    public FileResult File(string id)
    {
        string moviename;
        moviename =  (Session[id] as string);
        moviename = @"C:\dev\asp\hercules\hercules\Content\samples\" + moviename;
        //Session.Remove(id);

        return File(moviename, "video/mp4");
    }



    public FileStreamResult Stream(string id)
    {
        string moviename;
        moviename = Session[ id ] as string;
       // Session.Remove(id);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(moviename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return File(fs,"video/mp4");


    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem using the MVCResumingActions library from Codeplex (http://mvcresumingactions.codeplex.com/).

It appears that video players want to be able to make range-specific requests for the video, (in order to seek ahead, before the resource is fully loaded). If your response does not properly indicate that you support the capability, then all navigation is basically toasted.

So I started down that road, and found some good resources on the topic.

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Range-Specific-Requests-in-ASP-NET.aspx
http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/22533/1954?pf=true

But it was the MVCResumingActions project that provided the quickest and easiest path.

The project itself has no documentation, so here is what I did

1) If you don't have NuGet installed in your IDE, install it.

2) Install the package from the Package Manage Console

**PM> Install-Package MVC.ResumingActionResults**

3) In your controller, add this using clause

```
using VikingErik.Mvc.ResumingActionResults;
```

4) Then define your action method.

Declare it as one of the types provided by ResumingActionResults. I don't know how to use all of the types provided, but in my case In my case, I wanted to stream video, so I chose "ResumingFileStreamResult"

Here is my test action, located in my own "StreamController.cs" file. I named it "Viking" in honor of Erik

```
public ResumingFileStreamResult Viking (string file)

 {

  moviename = Server.MapPath("~/Content/samples/" + file);

  FileStream fs = new FileStream(moviename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

  ResumingFileStreamResult fsr = new ResumingFileStreamResult(fs,"video/mp4");

  return fsr;

}
```

Following is what I put in my view file:

```
<script src="http://api.html5media.info/1.1.5/html5media.min.js"></script>
 <video controls preload>
   <source src="/Stream/Viking?file=Chrome_ImF.mp4" />
 </video>
```

Voila, it worked like a charm.